# detect python-xmpp timeouts

Tags: python, timeout, xmpp, ping, disconnect

I have an application which shall send xmpp messages.  Those occasions are rare (sometimes none for days) but then again maybe coming in bunches.  I have no use of receiving anything, I just want to send.  The straight-forward approach runs into undetected timeouts.  The last `send()` does not take place (receiver does not get anything) but returns without reporting the problem (returns a simple id as if everything worked fine).  Only the *next* call to `send()` then raises an IOError('Disconnected from server.').

I could do a constant disconnect/reconnect for each message but I don't like this because sometimes this will disconnect and reconnect very often (and I don't know if servers appreciate on this multiple times in a second).

I could try the approach given as answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269441/simple-continuously-running-xmpp-client-in-python) here, but I do not really have a need for receiving the XMPP replies.

**Question:** Is there a simple way to **detect the connection timeout** before or after sending without trying to send a second message (which would spam the receiver in case everything worked fine)?

My straight-forward-approach:

```
import xmpp

def connectXmppClient(fromJidName, password):
  fromJid = xmpp.protocol.JID(fromJidName)
  xmppClient = xmpp.Client(fromJid.getDomain(), debug=[])
  connection = xmppClient.connect()
  if not connection:
    raise Exception("could not setup connection", fromJid)
  authentication = xmppClient.auth(
    fromJid.getNode(), password, resource=fromJid.getResource())
  if not authentication:
    raise Exception("could not authenticate")
  return xmppClient

def sendXmppMessage(xmppClient, toJidName, text):
  return xmppClient.send(xmpp.protocol.Message(toJidName, text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys, os, time, getpass
  if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Syntax: xsend fromJID toJID"
    sys.exit(0)
  fromJidName = sys.argv[1]
  toJidName = sys.argv[2]
  password = getpass.getpass()
  xmppClient = connectXmppClient(fromJidName, password)
  while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
      break
    print xmppClient.isConnected()
    id = sendXmppMessage(xmppClient, toJidName, line)
    print id
```

Comment: Why don't you put your `xmppClient.send` in `try: catch:`? You could just check the type of the exception. If it is an `IOError` then call your `connectXmppClient` again.

Comment: I've got a try/catch in place.  But as I wrote:  The IOError does not occur in the first call.  Only the next (which can be hours later) throws the exception I can catch.  That's not good.  I'd rather (of course) notice the connection breakdown on sending the first message, so I can quickly re-establish the connection and re-try to send that first message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a disconnect handler using [xmppClient.RegisterDisconnectHandler()](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/xmpp.client.CommonClient-class.html#RegisterDisconnectHandler).  This lets you specify a function that will get called upon a disconnect.

Comment: That disconnection handler (when registered using your way) gets not called upon sending the first message, sorry :-(  It gets called later, though, when I try to send the second message.  But then an exception is thrown anyway and I can react on that.

Thanks for your hint nevertheless, but I will have to go the long way and also receive messages from the server I guess.

Comment: Implemented receiving.  Let's see whether this solves my silent-logout issue.